# How to play a speex file in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

When i am pointing to an FlV it's playing successfully. But when it comes to a speex file. 
I am getting an error StreamnotFound. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flash Player does not support Speex codec and does not support adding codecs not built-into the player.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be difficult, you could implement the speex codec in Actionscript and use the Sound object's sampleData event to play it.

It would likely be far easier to convert speex to mp3 server-side.